# SharePoint API not fetching list items

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created an app in SharePoint online. This app's purpose is just to display the items of a list in current site. To get the data i wrote below simple script. But the data is coming with '0' length. that means it is reaching to my list but not able to fetch those items.

```
executor.executeAsync(
            {
                url:
                    hostweburl +
                    "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List_Name')/items",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: successHandler,
                error: errorHandler
            }
function successHandler(data) {
        var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body);
}
```

I am not even getting any error. Does any one have idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The URL format should be

```
executor.executeAsync(
                {
                  url:
                      appweburl +
                    "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items?@target='" +hostweburl + "'",
                  method: "GET",
                  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                  success: successHandler,
                  error: errorHandler
                }
            );
```